# " Never ship an app with prototyping constraints" what does it means in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

i am new to the ios and i was going through apple document  i found a line when-" Never ship an app with prototyping constraints" so does it means to design using coding then going with drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

> When you place a view on the canvas, Interface Builder automatically
>   creates a set of prototyping constraints that define the view’s
>   current size and position relative to the upper left corner.

– from [Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html)

So there are default constraints relative to top-left corner automatically "created" for you. But those are here to avoid to much warning when adding a lot of view.

You must define your own constraints, else the view won't adapt to different device screens.

> so does it means to design using coding then going with drag and drop

It doesn't matter if you create them within interface builder or within the code.

Comment: Thanks @Francescu but document stills say -The app can build and run with the prototyping constraints. Use these constraints to quickly visualize and test a user interface, but then replace the implicit constraints with your own explicit constraints. so which is better approach

Comment: Yes, because implicit constraints may work. But it's just convenient, not meant to be used at production.  For instance imagine that implicit constraints may change with a new iOS release

Answer (score 0):

It means (as in apple website)

> replace the implicit constraints with your own explicit constraints

so, either create it using code or add it to storyboard, don't rely on the ones that get added automatically in some cases.

Comment: if you combine implicit and explicit ones, bugs will happen, believe me, just build all the interface and constraints programmatically, you will have great control over everything, I tried both methods, programmatically was always better for me.